# building house aprox 150000 pounds using 6x6 posts--what is recomended spacing from 3ft high to 12 ft high

Tags: metal-roof

new home construction for home 36ft x 36ft with 8ft deck at high end. what should spacing 6x6 concreted in at 4ft deep with one end of house 3ft high and 12ft at high end with deck

Comment: So is this a house on stilts, built on a hillside?  That all I can figure out.  Where on the planet (country) is this?

Comment: House is on hillside in Arkansas. House will now be only 1ft at low end and on a concrete foundation with cinder blocks. Found out that bedrock is at average about 6ft deep in area so I will put post down to bedrock with end of deck at 10ft high end

Comment: @CharlesShafer Each 6x6 post will support about 26,000 lbs.  We need to know how many bearing walls lines, how many story and size of beam on bearing wall lines.

Comment: The house is a single story home with four load bearing wall inside + dividing four rooms 16x16 each with kitchen and laundry/bathroom at the low end. Deck will be uncovered and 8ft wide and width of house. Was planning on 8ft spacing but wanted to be sure if that was enough.

Answer (score 1):

**You need an engineer to know definitively what your requirements are for your location and design.** I am assuming you did not consult an engineer since they would have the spacing specified in the plans. ( *it is unlikely they would they have specified 4 feet deep* )

***We can not answer your question*** because we do not know the required info nor would it be wise for you to take advise from the internet instead of hiring a professional engineer.

*A friend of mine bought a house in foreclosure on the hillside of Anchorage many years ago.  It was built on 6"x6" timber piers some of which were only 4 to 5 feet deep as you plan to do. The house was listing badly at one corner as the piers at that end of the house had not been of sufficient depth.  He had to pay to have the house jack up and moved to a proper foundation we built. He then built another structure nearly on the same site as the older one. We hired a pile driver to drive 8" well casing pipe down to bedrock with steel I beams on top. It is not listing or sinking*.